# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource error when saving a web page with embedded pdf

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Site is zen cart. Trying to add

```
<embed src="pdf/timetable.pdf" height="1000" width="900"></embed>
```

to an ezpage. 
As soon as I click to update, I get a warning:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I checked cPanel logs and it shows 
[Mon Nov 25 08:32:31.650242 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 249998:tid 139962720311040] [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/mysitefolder/public_html/403.shtml, referer: http://example.com/admindir/ezpages.php?page=1&ezID=17&action=new

I checked htaccess, and in root htaccess file it has

```
# BEGIN CEON URI MAPPING REWRITE RULE
RewriteEngine On

# Don't rewrite any URIs ending with a file extension (ending with .[xxxxx])
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-z]{2,5}$ [NC]
# Don't rewrite any URIs for some, popular specific file format extensions,
# which are not covered by main file extension condition above
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(mp3|mp4|h264)$ [NC]
# Don't rewrite any URIs for some specific file format extensions,
#   which are not covered by main file extension condition above
#   Uncomment the following line to apply this condition! (Remove the # at the start of the next line)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(3gp|3g2|h261|h263|mj2|mjp2|mp4v|mpg4|m1v|m2v|m4u|f4v|m4v|3dml)$ [NC]
# Don't rewrite admin directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admindir [NC]
# Don't rewrite editors directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/editors/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite logs directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/logs/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite js directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite cgi-bin directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi\-bin/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite ajax directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ajax/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite kta directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/jrq/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite oexport directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oexport/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite min directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/min/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite tempEP directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tempEP/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite bmz_cache directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bmz_cache/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite pdf directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pdf/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite htmlincludes directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/htmlincludes/ [NC]
# Handle all other URIs using Zen Cart (its index.php)
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
## END CEON URI MAPPING REWRITE RULE
```

Then in the admin directory, there is another htaccess file containing

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
# deny *everything*
<FilesMatch ".*\..*">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# but now allow just *certain* necessary files:
<FilesMatch "(^$|^favicon.ico$|.*\.(php|js|css|jpg|gif|png|pdf)$)">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

IndexIgnore */*

# The following makes adjustments to the SSL protocol for    Internet Explorer browsers
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfDefine SSL>
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</IfDefine>
</IfModule>

#turn off X-PHP-Originating-Script header when sending emails from admin
#uncomment to activate:
# php_flag mail.add_x_header Off
```

Can anyone suggest what might be the problem here? Do I need to add something else to an htaccess file, or does my host need to change something in apache config?

Comment: What you quoted from the log sounds to me as if it wasn’t the real reason for the error, that is only the configured 403 error document not being accessible, so that should be an error resulting from the original one, but not the cause. Since you are only getting this when trying to save particular content, my first guess is it might have to do with XSS protection - not sure though, if that actually manifests in a 403, I think that is rather a client-side thing. Still, I’d try if explicitly disabling it changes things, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection

Comment: If that doesn’t help, then I’d start by enabling rewrite logging (careful with the log level, this can produce a lot of info), to see what exactly is going on in that regard internally.